# Updating wordpress in a multi-node environment

Tags: wordpress

I'm finding this very tricky in a multi node environment, with code under revision control. AKA. multiple frontends and single database. I have a deployment process that pushes a git repo to the servers, but obviously if I update Wordpress from within the admin panel, it will update the files to one FE. Then I would need to copy over the new files to the other FE nodes. Plus, whenever these changes are written when Wordpress updates on a node, it writes code into the git repo. As such, it then breaks the auto deploys that perform 'git pulls', as it then has untracked changes and refuses to pull in new deploys unless manually intervened.

How does one easily keep Wordpress updated in a multi node (load balanced) environment?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dedicated private admin instance and cron tasks to synchronize your service instances' filesystems periodically. You could use some kind of rsync process or an intermediate cloud storage service like Amazon S3 and sync tools like [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync).

I have successfully deployed some CMSs (including a Wordpress) in Amazon EC2 with autoscaling using the S3 based sync approach and, up to date , it's been working just great. I attach a example diagram of this setup.

[image: Elastic CMS example]

Comment: The admin page hits a different node each time (load balanced). There would be no way of knowing which is the sync master.

Comment: That's why I suggest using a private instance, dettached from the load balancer. Service instances should have web server level rules to explicitly deny the admin interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't think that will cover the aspect of the deploys. AKA. even if I use a private admin interface and update that, I would still need to commit that update to the repo, where at the moment the frontend is only being pushed to (not from).

Comment: Forget about GIT or any other versioning system in your service instances. You should only need it in your admin instance to push/pull whenever you require it. Service instances synchronization will eventually happen, depending on your S3 sync schedule.